# Is there a way to make this Custom SQL export just look at the processed orders from the last day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

Hope someone can help with some advise, I do not have much coding background (basic Python only).

We are using a custom export from Linnworks WMS to invoicing automatically with Tradebox but, it has stopped working because of a missing Billing Name in one of our processed orders.

The code used to create the CSV is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.dReceievedDate, 103) AS 'Order Date', 
o.nOrderId AS 'Order ID', 
'Channel Reference ID' = CASE
    WHEN o.Source = 'EBAY' THEN o.SecondaryReferenceNum
    ELSE o.ReferenceNum
    END, 
oi.ItemNumber AS 'Item ID', 
'SKU' = CASE 
    WHEN pis.pkStockItemID IS NOT NULL THEN pis.ItemNumber 
    WHEN si.pkStockItemID IS NOT NULL THEN si.ItemNumber
    WHEN oi.ChannelSKU IS NOT NULL THEN oi.ChannelSKU 
    ELSE 'SKU Not Supplied' 
    END,
'Product Name' = CASE 
    WHEN pis.pkStockItemID IS NOT NULL THEN pis.ItemTitle 
    WHEN si.pkStockItemID IS NOT NULL THEN si.ItemTitle 
    WHEN sis.cItemName IS NOT NULL THEN sis.cItemName 
    ELSE 'Product Name Not Supplied' 
    END, 
'Currency' = CASE o.cCurrency 
    WHEN '' THEN 'GBP' 
    WHEN '$' THEN 'USD' 
    WHEN '' THEN 'EUR' 
    WHEN '' THEN 'GBP' 
    ELSE o.cCurrency 
    END, 
CASE WHEN oi.LineDiscount =0 THEN (oi.CostIncTax/ oi.nQty) ELSE CAST( (oi.CostIncTax +(oi.CostIncTax 
* oi.LineDiscount  / (100 -oi.LineDiscount ))) / oi.nQty AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) END AS  'Product Price', 
oi.nQty AS 'Quantity', 
o.fPostageCost AS 'Carriage Amount', 
CASE WHEN oi.LineDiscount =0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(oi.CostIncTax * oi.LineDiscount  / (100 - 
oi.LineDiscount ) / oi.nQty AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) END AS 'Discount', 
ISNULL(b.AccountName, '') AS 'Payment Method',
ps.PostalServiceName AS 'Shipping Method', 
'Billing Name' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingName,o.cFullName),'"',''), 
'Billing Company Name' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingCompany,o.Company),'"',''), 
'Billing Address 1' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingAddress1, o.Address1),'"',''), 
'Billing Address 2' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingAddress2, o.Address2),'"',''), 
'Billing Address 3' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingTown, o.Town),'"',''), 
'Billing Address 4' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingRegion, o.Region),'"',''), 
'Billing Address 5' = REPLACE(ISNULL(oia.BillingPostcode, o.cPostCode),'"',''), 
'Billing Country' = ISNULL(oia.BillingCountryName, lc.cCountry), 
'Billing Country Code' = CASE lc.cCountryCode 
    WHEN 'UNK' THEN 'GB' 
    ELSE ISNULL(billcountry.cCountryCode,lc.cCountryCode) 
    END, o.cEmailAddress AS 'Customer Email', 
o.BuyerPhoneNumber AS 'Customer Telephone', 
o.cFullName AS 'Shipping Name',
REPLACE(o.Company,'"','') AS 'Shipping Company Name', 
REPLACE(o.Address1,'"','') AS 'Shipping Address 1', 
REPLACE(o.Address2,'"','') AS 'Shipping Address 2',
REPLACE(o.Town,'"','') AS 'Shipping Address 3', 
REPLACE(o.Region,'"','') AS 'Shipping Address 4', 
REPLACE(o.cPostCode,'"','') AS 'Shipping Address 5', 
lc.cCountry AS 'Shipping Country', 
lc.cCountryCode AS 'Shipping Country Code', 
'Order Status' = CASE o.nStatus
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Complete' 
    END, 
'Marketplace' = CASE o.SubSource
    WHEN '' THEN o.Source
    ELSE o.Source + ' ' + o.SubSource
    END
FROM
[Order] o 
INNER JOIN OrderItem oi WITH(NOLOCK) ON oi.fkOrderID = o.pkOrderID 
INNER JOIN StockItems sis WITH(NOLOCK) ON sis.pkStockID = oi.fkStockID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockItem si WITH(NOLOCK) ON sis.fkStockControlStockItemId = si.pkStockItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockItem pis WITH(NOLOCK) ON pis.pkStockItemID = oi.fkStockItemId_processed 
INNER JOIN PostalServices ps WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.fkPostalServiceId = ps.pkPostalServiceId 
INNER JOIN ListCountries lc WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.fkCountryId = lc.pkCountryId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_AdditionalInfo oia WITH(NOLOCK) ON oia.fkOrderId = o.pkOrderID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounting_Bank b WITH(NOLOCK) ON b.pkBankId = o.fkBankId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        cCountry,cCountryCode=MAX(cCountryCode) 
    FROM ListCountries 
    WHERE bLogicalDelete=0 
    GROUP BY cCountry) AS billcountry ON billcountry.cCountry = oia.BillingCountryName 
 WHERE 
(oi.fkCompositeParentRowId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' OR oi.fkCompositeParentRowId IS 
NULL) 
AND o.nStatus = 1 
AND (o.dReceievedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(M,-1,GetDATE()) AND GETDATE()) 
AND o.dProcessedOn IS NOT NULL 
AND o.bProcessed = 1 
ORDER BY 
o.dReceievedDate ,o.nOrderId
```

Is there a way to make this Custom SQL export just look at the processed orders from the last couple days?

This would stop the file size from getting to big (as it keeps growing each day at the moment) and stop the error from affecting the csv for too long.
we have a way to remove the error and upload the csv manually should we encounter a similar error again.

We are open to any other possible solutions that anyone comes up with.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Andrew Reeves

Comment: Most probably `AND (o.dReceievedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(M,-1,GetDATE()) AND GETDATE())` => `AND (o.dReceievedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(D,-2,GetDATE()) AND GETDATE()) `

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). And no one but you knows precisely what "processed orders from last day" (or last couple of days?) means as it relates to your schema. Seems like that logic is based on `o.dProcessedOn `? If so, add the desired logic to the WHERE clause.